# Question should be removed from audit queue

Tags: discussion, disputed-review-audits

I failed this audit: https://stackoverflow.com/review/reopen/5684920 (or: [In C++, how does strict bottom-up analysis imply that the return type is not used in overloading resolution?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25548864/in-c-how-does-strict-bottom-up-analysis-imply-that-the-return-type-is-not-use)). The question was closed as primary opinion-based.

I clicked *leave closed*, *also* because the question might be better suited for Programmers.SE

I suggest to take it out of the audit pool because the test is ambiguous.

BTW: Is there a generic place (meta post) to report this, instead of starting a new meta question for each disputed failed audit. I could not find it.

Comment: The question wasn't closed at all; you failed the audit. If you want to take it out of the audits list just vote to close...

Comment: Huh? *While I was writing this question* another browser tab was open with the 'Stop look and listen' etc. texts. And indeed it is just an open question now. But if I click that first link it definitely says "Review audit failed 13 mins ago: Jan Doggen reviewed this 13 mins ago: Leave Closed"

Comment: ...Yes? You voted to leave closed an open question. Isn't that failing the audit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no generic meta post to post questions such as this one as it is not necessary.  You have the ability to remove a question as consideration from future close vote/reopen vote audits yourself.

Audits are selected automatically, and one of the criteria for selecting close and reopen audits are the presence of any close votes.  A "known-good" audit (which is what you encountered) will be selected from recent questions that have never received a close vote.  The moment you vote to close it from the question page itself (not the audit page), it will no longer be considered for future audits.

---

As for the question itself, I hope you didn't decide to click "Leave Closed" only because you thought it would be better on Programmers.  Questions can be on-topic on multiple sites and just because it might be *better* on one site doesn't mean it should be closed on a different.

Personally, I would have skipped this question, so I can't tell you whether the audit is a good one or a bad one.  The question certainly looks like it could be opinion-based but since the topic well is outside of my comfort zone, I wouldn't have touched it.

Comment: I see. Yes I have learned to click 'Skip' when I'm doubting, obviously I should have done that here too. What confused me is indeed the difference between *voting to leave closed* in the audit and *voting to close* when encountering the question. But the whole issue is of course **that we are not supposed to know that difference** when we are presented with an audit. Tricky. Not that I mind failing an audit now and then, I just thought there was an error in the selection of the audit question.

Comment: @JanDoggen the fact that you aren't supposed to know it is an audit is somewhat inaccurate.  If you are paying attention and doing a thorough job as a reviewer than many audits are obvious.  The developers have said this is by design as audits are designed to catch people who robotically click "Leave Open" or "Looks OK" in efforts to get badges and not help contribute to the quality of the site.  If you see an obvious audit question, then just do what the audit wants to do even if you disagree.  Then directly go to the post in question and handle the question how you think it should be handled

Comment: @JanDoggen of course all audits are not obvious (and some are flat out bad) because of the automatic nature that audit questions are selected.  This is unavoidable without requiring a human to manually select every audit (and even then you'll have people disagree).

Comment: Thanks, noting that and doing that already, this situation was new to me. The 'edit audits' with all their random words inserted are particularly funny. But as you said, it's just to prevent the robotically inclined.